# Is it mandatory to have @PathParam argument and function argument same in a rest controller

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am writing a Controller in a Springboot aplictaion. Afunction call looks like

```
@GetMapping("/data/search")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> searchData(@PathParam("name") String dataName,
    ....
```

When I run this in debug mode with the url as `.../data/search?name=abc` , I get a  `null` value for the variable `dataName`.
Whereas I get the value `abc` in case I update the variable name
 `dataName->name`

As per the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WINK/JAX-RS+Parameters), I should have used `@QueryParam`, but that makes no difference either.

So is it mandatory to have the variable name same as the param name?

Comment: I think you want @RequestParam.

Comment: Yes, `@RequestParam` does it for me. But the document I cited clearly mentions an example with `@QueryParam`.

Comment: Thanks @onnoweb. This is from springboot for binding web request parameter to a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

@PathParam is mandatory and must be passed via path in your case should be /data/search/{name} and then can be accessed. No defaults allowed for path parameters.

for ex: http://serverhost/data/search/test

On the other hand @RequestParam can have a default value and can be optional in your url

for ex: http://serverhost/data/search?name=test